# Pass "Extra" value from angular to method in MVC

Tags: angularjs

I got this piece of angularJS in my app:

```
<div data-ng-controller="GetCategory">    
        <div>
            Välj Kategori:
            <select data-ng-model="activities.header"
                    data-ng-options="a.header for a in activities"></select>
        </div>

        <p>{{ activities.header.header}}</p> 
        Vald Id: {{ activities.header.id}}
    </div>
```

The above code renders a dropdown-menu and the choosen value ends up in:

```
<p>{{ activities.header.header}}</p>
```

What i would like to do is to save the value in the:

```
<p>{{ activities.header.header}}</p>
```

So i can pass it along with this:

```
 $scope.save = function () {

                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/Home/SaveListFromAngular',
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                    },
                    data: { todos: $scope.todos, var x : "{{ activities.header.header}}"}
                });
            }
```

Im trying to illustrate what i want to do here:

```
 data: { todos: $scope.todos, var x : "{{ activities.header.header}}"}
```

Hope Im clear enough for someone. Thanks!

Comment: Right away you have syntax error.. :) You want to do `data: { todos: $scope.todos, header: $scope.activities.header.header}` perhaps?

Comment: This is not the complete code, of course im not trying to pass:
var x : "{{ activities.header.header}}"}  in this manner, im only trying to illustrate what im trying to accomplish. I.E, pass the value in my post. The code works. Thank you

Comment: oh ok... My bad in understanding the question... :)

Comment: I think you've made a typo in your question. You say that it's already saved to `<p>{{activities.header.header}}</p>`. Is that correct?

Comment: Well no, whatever item i chose in the dropdown shows up in 
<p>{{ activities.header.header}}</p>, i dunno if that means that its saved there..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all you need to do here is stringify the activities.header.header and send it.  So, it would look like this...

```
$scope.save = function () {
    var theHeader = JSON.stringify($scope.activities.header.header)
      , theTodos = JSON.stringify($scope.todos);

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/Home/SaveListFromAngular',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        data: { todos: theTodos , x : theHeader}
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This seem like an interesting solution, however, my method in MVC does not get hit when i try it, here is my methods parameters:
 public ActionResult SaveListFromAngular(List<Todo> todos, string x)

Comment: oh, sorry. I was only focused on the header.  Couple of things here.  First make sure that you stringify the todos object also.  Second, you may want to create a view model to pass in on the .Net side.  As in, TodoViewModel {List<Todo> todos, string x}, then SaveListFromAngular(TodoViewModel model).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time! Im a beginenr with Angular, would you mind updating your answer with how I can stringify both objects? On the .NET-side, I have a a ToDo-viewmodel. Thats the one I use to save the values sent to the method. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much!
Sorry for taking a long time to accept your answer =)

Comment: Hmm, im still having problems here, it seems that if I stringyfy an object in this manner, the method will stop right there. Tried adding a alert(theHeader) after the var gets declared but it does not get hit.